# Redraw three js element

Tags: javascript, three.js, frontend

I looked at [this example](https://codepen.io/Mamboleoo/pen/wKqwPN) with three js to draw particles with images and works perfectly but i want to change the image with a switch when click a button (calls this function):

```
    const changeImg = function(num) {

    switch (num)
    {
        case 0:
            imgData ="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAA....";
        break;

        case 1:
            imgData = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAAN..."
        break;
    }

    img.src = imgData;

}
```

And works but when you click multiple times website becomes slow.

How can I update just the image without slowing down the website?

**EDIT 1**

I change the code like this:

```js
var renderer, scene, camera, ww, wh, particles, mw, mh, mz, numState;

numState = 0;

mz = 6; // Matrerial size

ww = document.getElementById('map-container').offsetWidth,
wh = 450;

mw = ww * 2;
mh = wh * 2;

var centerVector = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
var previousTime = 0
    speed = 10
    isMouseDown = false;

// Render
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    canvas: document.getElementById("map"),
    antialias: true
});

renderer.setSize(mw, mh);
renderer.setClearColor(0x12347C);

// Scence
scene = new THREE.Scene();

// Camera
camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera( ww / - 2, ww / 2, wh / 2, wh / - 2, 1, 1000 );
camera.position.set(7, 0, 4);
camera.lookAt(centerVector);
scene.add(camera);
camera.zoom = 4;
camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

// Geometry
var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
var material = new THREE.PointsMaterial({
    size: mz,
    color: 0xFFFFFF,
    sizeAttenuation: false
});

// Particle
particles = new THREE.Points();

var getImageData = function(image) {

    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = image.width;
    canvas.height = image.height;

    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);

    return ctx.getImageData(0, 0, image.width, image.height);
}

var drawTheMap = function() {

    geometry.dispose();
    particles.material.dispose();
    particles.geometry.dispose();

    for (var y = 0, y2 = imagedata.height; y < y2; y += 2) {
        for (var x = 0, x2 = imagedata.width; x < x2; x += 2) {
            if (imagedata.data[(x * 4 + y * 4 * imagedata.width)] < 128) {

                var vertex = new THREE.Vector3();
                vertex.x = x - imagedata.width / 2;
                vertex.y = -y + imagedata.height / 2;
                vertex.z = -Math.random()*500;

                vertex.speed = Math.random() / speed + 0.015;

                geometry.vertices.push(vertex);
            }
        }
    }

    particles.material = material;
    particles.geometry = geometry;

    scene.add(particles);

    requestAnimationFrame(render);
};

var init = function() {

    imagedata = getImageData(image);
    drawTheMap();

    onResize();

    window.addEventListener('mousemove', onMousemove, false);
    window.addEventListener('mousedown', onMousedown, false);
    window.addEventListener('mouseup', onMouseup, false);
    window.addEventListener('resize', onResize, false);

};


var onResize = function(){

    var mov1, mov2;

    ww = document.getElementById('map-container').offsetWidth;
    wh = 450;
    
    if (window.innerWidth > 850) {
        mw = ww * 2;
        mh = wh * 2;
        mz = 6;

        mov1 = 2.2;
        mov2 = 1.9;

        particles.material.size = mz;
    } else {
        mw = ww;
        mh = wh;
        mz = 3;

        mov1 = 2;
        mov2 = 2;

        particles.material.size = mz;
    }

    renderer.setSize(mw, mh);
    camera.left    = ww / - mov1;
    camera.right   = ww / 2;
    camera.top     = wh / mov2;
    camera.bottom  = wh / - 2;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
};

var onMouseup = function(){
    isMouseDown = false;
}
var onMousedown = function(e){
    isMouseDown = true;
    lastMousePos = {x:e.clientX, y:e.clientY};
};
var onMousemove = function(e){
    
    if(isMouseDown){
        camera.position.x += (e.clientX-lastMousePos.x)/100;
        camera.position.y -= (e.clientY-lastMousePos.y)/100;
        camera.lookAt(centerVector);
        lastMousePos = {x:e.clientX, y:e.clientY};
    }
};

var render = function(a) {

    requestAnimationFrame(render);

    particles.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
    if(!isMouseDown){
        camera.position.x += (0-camera.position.x)*0.06;
        camera.position.y += (0-camera.position.y)*0.06;
        camera.lookAt(centerVector);
    }

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
};

var imgData;
var image;
imgData ="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAA...";

const changeState = function(state, num) {

    document.getElementById('dropbox-choose').innerHTML = state;
    numState = num;

    switch (numState)
    {
        case 0:
            imgData ="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAA...";
        break;

        case 1:
            imgData = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoI..."
        break;
    }

    image.src = imgData;
}

image = document.createElement("img");
image.onload = init;
image.src = imgData;
```

And the THREE.WebGLRenderer is only applied once but when I click to change the image, it does not update and also I still have the problem that the website slows down

it's my first time using three js and i don't know if i'm applying well what it says in the documentation

**EDIT 2**

```js
var renderer, scene, camera, ww, wh, particles, mw, mh, mz, numState;

numState = 0;

mz = 6;
ww = document.getElementById('map-container').offsetWidth,
wh = 450;

mw = ww * 2;
mh = wh * 2;

var centerVector = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
var previousTime = 0
    speed = 10
    isMouseDown = false;

// Render
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    canvas: document.getElementById("map"),
    antialias: true
});

renderer.setSize(mw, mh);
renderer.setClearColor(0x12347C);

// Scence
scene = new THREE.Scene();

// Camera
camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera( ww / - 2, ww / 2, wh / 2, wh / - 2, 1, 1000 );
camera.position.set(7, 0, 4);
camera.lookAt(centerVector);
scene.add(camera);
camera.zoom = 4;
camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

// Geometry
//var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
var material = new THREE.PointsMaterial({
    size: mz,
    color: 0xFFFFFF,
    sizeAttenuation: false
});

// Particle
particles = new THREE.Points();
particles.material = material

scene.add(particles);

var getImageData = function(image) {

    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = image.width;
    canvas.height = image.height;

    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);

    return ctx.getImageData(0, 0, image.width, image.height);
}

var drawTheMap = function() {

    let vertices = particles.geometry; // this acts as a REFERENCE!
    vertices.length = 0; // clears the vertices array


    for (var y = 0, y2 = imagedata.height; y < y2; y += 2) {
        for (var x = 0, x2 = imagedata.width; x < x2; x += 2) {
            if (imagedata.data[(x * 4 + y * 4 * imagedata.width)] < 128) {

                var vertex = new THREE.Vector3();
                vertex.x = x - imagedata.width / 2;
                vertex.y = -y + imagedata.height / 2;
                vertex.z = -Math.random()*500;

                vertex.speed = Math.random() / speed + 0.015;

                vertices.vertices.push(vertex);
            }
        }
    }

    particles.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true; // Inform three.js of the update

    requestAnimationFrame(render);
};

var init = function() {

    imagedata = getImageData(image);
    drawTheMap();

    onResize();

    window.addEventListener('mousemove', onMousemove, false);
    window.addEventListener('mousedown', onMousedown, false);
    window.addEventListener('mouseup', onMouseup, false);
    window.addEventListener('resize', onResize, false);

};


var onResize = function(){

    var mov1, mov2;

    ww = document.getElementById('map-container').offsetWidth;
    wh = 450;
    
    if (window.innerWidth > 850) {
        mw = ww * 2;
        mh = wh * 2;
        mz = 6;

        mov1 = 2.2;
        mov2 = 1.9;

        particles.material.size = mz;
    } else {
        mw = ww;
        mh = wh;
        mz = 3;

        mov1 = 2;
        mov2 = 2;

        particles.material.size = mz;
    }

    renderer.setSize(mw, mh);
    camera.left    = ww / - mov1;
    camera.right   = ww / 2;
    camera.top     = wh / mov2;
    camera.bottom  = wh / - 2;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
};

var onMouseup = function(){
    isMouseDown = false;
}
var onMousedown = function(e){
    isMouseDown = true;
    lastMousePos = {x:e.clientX, y:e.clientY};
};
var onMousemove = function(e){
    if(isMouseDown){
        camera.position.x += (e.clientX-lastMousePos.x)/100;
        camera.position.y -= (e.clientY-lastMousePos.y)/100;
        camera.lookAt(centerVector);
        lastMousePos = {x:e.clientX, y:e.clientY};
    }
};

var render = function(a) {

    requestAnimationFrame(render);

    particles.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
    if(!isMouseDown){
        camera.position.x += (0-camera.position.x)*0.06;
        camera.position.y += (0-camera.position.y)*0.06;
        camera.lookAt(centerVector);
    }

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
};

var imgData;
var image;
imgData ="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAA...";

const changeState = function(state, num) {

    document.getElementById('dropbox-choose').innerHTML = state;
    numState = num;

    switch (numState)
    {
        case 0:
            imgData ="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAA...";
        break;

        case 1:
            imgData = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAA..."
        break;
    }

    image.src = imgData;
}

image = document.createElement("img");
image.onload = init;
image.src = imgData;
```

When I click to change the image, it does not update and also I still have the problem that the website slows down. I cahaged vertcies.push to vertices.vertices.push()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is change THREE.geometry to THREE.BufferGeometry

```js
var drawTheMap = function() {
    particles.geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
    var positions = [];

    for (var y = 0, y2 = imagedata.height; y < y2; y += 2) {
        for (var x = 0, x2 = imagedata.width; x < x2; x += 2) {
            if (imagedata.data[(x * 4 + y * 4 * imagedata.width)] < 128)  {

                positions.push(x - imagedata.width / 2);
                positions.push(-y + imagedata.height / 2);
                positions.push(-Math.random()*500);

                particles.geometry.setAttribute( 'position', new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute( positions, 3 ) );

            }
        }
    }
    
      particles.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;

    requestAnimationFrame(render);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I mentioned disposal in a previous version of my answer, but let's instead consider re-using all of your objects.

`particles` - Add it to the scene immediately after creation.

`material` - Assign it to `particles` immediately; No need to re-assign it every time.

`geometry` - Don't create it globally, we'll let it work from within `particles`.

Now what we're going to do is *replace* the vertices and tell three.js that there are new vertices to upload to the GPU.

```js
var drawTheMap = function() {

    let vertices = particles.geometry; // this acts as a REFERENCE!
    vertices.length = 0; // clears the vertices array

    for (var y = 0, y2 = imagedata.height; y < y2; y += 2) {
        for (var x = 0, x2 = imagedata.width; x < x2; x += 2) {
            if (imagedata.data[(x * 4 + y * 4 * imagedata.width)] < 128) {

                var vertex = new THREE.Vector3();
                vertex.x = x - imagedata.width / 2;
                vertex.y = -y + imagedata.height / 2;
                vertex.z = -Math.random()*500;

                vertex.speed = Math.random() / speed + 0.015;

                vertices.push(vertex);
            }
        }
    }

    particles.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true; // Inform three.js of the update

    requestAnimationFrame(render);
};
```

The important part here (other than replacing the contents of the `vertices` array) is setting `particles.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;`. This is what triggers three.js to replace the vertices on the GPU. Everything else is re-used, not recreated, so it should run fairly smooth.

Comment: I have changed the code but now I have other problems. update the post with the new code

Comment: Hi. I have changed the code as you told me but it still doesn't work. I update the question with the latest code I have.